# Why don't we calculate time for a packet to get OUT of the wire?

Tags: terminology

When calculating the end-to-end delay, [Transmission Delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_delay) is the time need to pump / put the bits onto the wire. Why isn't it the case that end-to-end delay also include the time need to get the bits ***from / out of*** the wire?

Comment: We do.  That's called processing delay.

Comment: @RonTrunk can you please provide a reference that states that? I am under the impression that 'processing delay' refers to calculating things based on the packet headers and *not* getting bits out of the wire.

Comment: "Getting bits out of the wire" is a colloquial expression.  Reading the header is exactly what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can you please provide a reference that states that?

An excerpt from *Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach* by Kurose and Ross (pp. 36-37):

> The time required the packet's header and determine where to direct the packet is part of the **processing delay**. The processing delay can also include other factors, such as the time needed to check for bit-level errors in the packet that occurred in transmitting the packet's bits from the upstream node to router A. Processing delays in high-speed routers are typically on the order of microseconds or less. After this nodal processing, the router directs the packet to the queue that precedes the link to router B.

Answer (score 1):

Bits go to and from the wire at the speed of the wire. This is called serialization. Bits to a 100 Mbps link are serialized at 100 Mbps. They cannot be serialized any faster than the link can take them, and if they were serialized any slower, then the transfer on the link wouldn't be 100 Mbps.

Some people refer to serialization delay, but that is the slowing of the data from the (usually) higher speed of the data transfer in the host to the speed of the link.